# QGIS: Placing points on a shapefile in relation to their distance to other points on that shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinates, linear-referencing

I'm attempting to add UK railway signal-boxes to QGIS to extract their coordinates - there's over 1000 of them.

I have:

- The entire UK railway network shapefile
- The coordinates of train stations on the railways
- The distances of the signal-boxes from the closest train station

I was planning to obtain the signal-box locations based on their distances from other train stations.

However, I don't know a direct way of splitting the railway network into smaller segments in order to use methods like Linear Referencing. I was also hoping, if it's possible to segment the network, to name each line segment and add the signal-boxes based on this name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: LRS plugin for QGIS https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/lrs/ more info http://blazek.github.io/lrs/release/help.0.3.5/index.html